# Error in finding user id from chatbox name

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, mongodb, express

I am currently doing a project on online chatbox. However, i was stuck when I need to get the id of friends of the user by getting the name of the friend(eg. when i have Ivan in my friendList, I can get his id in the database) when logging in the server. I can get the name of the friend, say, Ivan, but i tried many times and still dont know how to use the name i found to find the id of Ivan in the server. I am using mongodb and node.js to do this project. Here is my current code:

```
router.get('/load', function(req, res)
var db = req.db;
var collection = db.get('userList')
if(req.session.userId)
{
 var id = req.session.userId;
 collection.find({"_id": id},{fields:{"_id":0, "friends.name":1}}, function(err, docs)
 res.json(docs);
 )}
 }
```

And here's what the database structure kind of looks like:

```
{
 "_id": ObjectId(5a23e06aa11f6589e02d8fcf),
 "name": "Ken",
 "password": "12345678",
 "friends":[
   {
     "name" : "Andy",
     "lastmsg": "0"
    },
    {
     "name" : "Ivan",
      "lastmsg" : "1"
     }
    ]
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try

```
collection.findOne({"friends.name": "Ivan"}, function(err, docs)
 res.json(docs);
)}
```